# how to make my output without the " ' , [

Tags: python, list, format

```
l1 = ['apple','banana','carrot','juice']

print(l1)
```

How can I get the output from looking like this: `['apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'juice']`

To looking like this: `apple banana carrot juice`

This is just a brief example but still gets the point across about how I can format my output from a list to look better?

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = ['apple','banana','carrot','juice']

text = " ".join([str(x) for x in l1])
print(text)
```

Comment: or just `' '.join(l1)` if all elements are already `str`

Comment: true im this using for numbers + text :D